# Hadoop and MS SQL Server Best Practices

Tags: sql, database, hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing

I've been following Hadoop for a while, it seems like a great technology. The Map/Reduce, Clustering it's just good stuff. But I haven't found any article regarding the use of Hadoop with SQL Server.

Let's say I have a huge claims table (600 million rows) and I want to take advantage of Hadoop. I was thinking but correct me if I'm wrong, I can query my table and extract all of my data and insert it into hadoop in chunks of any type (xml, json, csv). Then I can take advantage of Map/Reduce and Clustering with at least 6 machines and leave my SQL Server for other tasks. I'm just throwing a bone here I just want to know if anybody has done such a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing and exporting data to and from a relational database is a very common use-case for Hadoop.  Take a look at Cloudera's Sqoop utility, which will aid you in this process:

http://incubator.apache.org/projects/sqoop.html